# WeChat authentication for web

Tags: node.js, passport.js, wechat

I am creating a web app and I have implemented authentication using Facebook, Google. Now I want to authenticate using weChat. I understand I need to use "passport-wechat-auth" but for that I need to create wechat account and that throws me failure each time. SO if anyone have better idea to implement it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you must have a official wechat account to implement. For authentication as like FB etc, you an use WeChat-oauth npm module to do it.

In-Case if you don't have a actual official account. You can use sandbox account for development.[Wechat Sandbox](http://admin.wechat.com/debug/sandbox)